# Server with multi-processor, how to launch code

Tags: parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-usage

I don't have a big knowledge in hardware, GPU and CPU so I'm trying to create it. I have a server with N processor, the description for each of them is more or less the following one:

```
processor   : 63
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 25
model       : 1
model name  : AMD EPYC 7313 16-Core Processor
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0xa001119
cpu MHz     : 3724.322
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 32
core id     : 15
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 63
initial apicid  : 63
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
```

I don't have a job scheduler, so I'm using tmux or screen to deal with my code.

How can I deal with the processor and use like 3 of them, or less or more, and run my python code? I'm very confused about that.

Comment: If you're absolutely sure you want to use 3 processors exclusively for some of your tasks, do the combination of following: set 3 cores as isolated in the Linux kernel command line, and then pin your processess (or threads) to those cores, they'll have an exclusive ownership of them. Although, as you're using Python, I'd expect the kernel scheduler to do a better job anyway, so you should not bother with affinity and isolation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to divide your work into tasks that can run independently from each other and then have them in their own processes via forking (if they don't need to communicate with each other and e.g. just store their results somewhere on disk) or create threads to run them.

A single thread will always only use a single CPU, you need multiple threads to use more CPUs. Each process has at least one thread, that's why creating multiple processes would work, too.

Since you mention `tmux`, maybe bash's job control can help you - short example would be `my_script.py input_file & my_script.py another_input_file`, starting two instances of `my_script.py` to run at the same time.